# PHP FileUpload is not working

Tags: php, file-upload

I am on Ubuntu. I am trying to take user file upload of small images. I checked the $_FILES it's filled with data. I tried to debug the move command but it doesnot echo anything.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ){
    //Now handle everything
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        print_r($_FILES);
        //Store the image
        if(!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file']))
        {
          $path = "/neel/public/img/";
          $path = $path.basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
          if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {

            echo 'Its working';
          } else{
              echo 'I am done!!!';
              die();
          }
        } 
    createnewEvent($conn);
    header('Location:/neel/index.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the <form page?

Comment: <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/neel/admin.php" method="post">

Comment: So what you show is the /neel/admin.php. Do you get any output?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the file exists by checking its name.

```
if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name']))
```

Where `file` is the name of input field for file.

Comment: did that did not help

Answer (score 0):

The script you've shown shown will only "not echo anything" if $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] is not "POST". Assuming your description of events is accurate, then the problem is in the form @halojoy has asked that you show here.

I do hope that you are not redirecting the script back to itself. Also you shouldn't attempt to do a redirect after an echo.

Comment: <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/neel/admin.php" method="post">

Comment: 1) that's only part of the form. 2) the code you've shown us will not behave in the way you describe (unless it has crashed with a core dump). We can't help if you can't describe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

P. G above here is correct.
Instead of checking, if $_POST['submit']
You should check this:
`if(isset($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it's a complete sign up form with PHP , Bootstrap

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <br>
            <h1 class="text-center">Create new account</h1>
            <br>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="name" placeholder="Your Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group text-center">
                    <div class='file-input'>
                        <input type='file' name="profile-img">
                        <span class='button label' data-js-label>Choose your profile image</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success form-control form-control-lg" name="signup" value="Signup">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

PHP

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $errors;
    if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
        $errors[] = "Name field is empty";
    }
    if (empty($_POST['username'])) {
        $errors[] = "Username field is empty";
    }
    if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $errors[] = "Password field is empty";
    }
    if (empty($_FILES['profile-img'])) {
        $errors[] = "You should upload profile image";
    } else{
        $img = $_FILES['profile-img'];
        $ext = end(explode('.', $img['name']));
        $allowed_extensions = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');
        $max_size = 4; //MegaBytes
        if (! in_array($ext, $allowed_extensions)) {
            $errors[] = "Please , Choose a valid image";
        }
        $img_size = $img['size'] / 1000000; // By Megabyte
        if ($img_size > $max_size) {
            $errors[] = "This picture is so large";
        }
    }
    if (!empty($errors)) {
        echo '<div class="container">';
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            echo '
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                ' . $error . '
                </div>
            ';
        }
        echo "</div>";
    } else {
        $username = filter_var(htmlentities(trim($_POST['username'])), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $name = filter_var(htmlentities(trim($_POST['name'])), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $password = sha1(filter_var(htmlentities(trim($_POST['password'])), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
        // Profile Picture :-
        $imgname = uniqid(uniqid()) . @date("Y-m-d") . "." . $ext;

        $target_bath = "uploads/imgs/";
        $target_bath = $target_bath . basename($imgname);
        $orginal_img = $img['tmp_name'];

        if (move_uploaded_file($orginal_img, $target_bath)) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO users(name, username, password,profile_picture, r_d) VALUES ('$name', '$username', '$password', '$target_bath', NOW())";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            header('location: ./login.php');
        }


    }
}
```